# Simple web front-end for editing mail aliases

Tags: postfix, email-server, exim, mail-forwarding

I want to run a mail server (either Postfix or Exim) solely for redirecting mail aliases.

Its entire function will be to process a table of users for a domain (e.g. springfield-nuclear-environmental-squad.info) that looks like this:

```
lenny: lenny@gmail.com
carl: carl@yahoo.com
smithers: iHeartMrBurns@hotmail.com
```

However, I'd like a nice web interface for this so that the Springfield Nuclear helpdesk can add people without having to have access to a shell on the server.

The simpler the better; I would rather not have to use a database if possible.  I could also knock something up myself in LAMP, but would prefer to use an "off-the-shelf", open source, component, if one exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I have found [Postfix Admin](http://postfixadmin.sourceforge.net/), which looks like it would do the job, but it requires MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Comment: Used for years with satisfaction